# How to self-boot in Android with React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I want my app to start up and run on Android every time I boot it up again

I tried what I found

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

Settings in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:enabled="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter >
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But this method does not have any effect in my application it does not boot, I wonder if there is any way to implement this method in ReactNative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that can be used at present. I do not know whether it can be used in this way on other devices. After testing, it can run normally:
Step 1:
In `app->main->java->com.youProject`
Create a new Java file, for example mine called BootReceiver
The code is as follows:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(myIntent);
}}
```

What's missing, just import it.

Step 2:
In `main->AndroidManifest.xml`
In `<application>` Add in

```
<receiver android:name="com.intelligentcontroller.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Add `android:enabled="true"` in `<application>`
[This is the information that I found that if you don't add it to your application you won't be able to instantiate](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element)

Step 3:
Get broadcast permissions in the outermost manifest (I'm not sure)`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />` so you can get the desired result and run it automatically at boot time

result:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<application
    android:name=".MainApplication"
    android:allowBackup="false"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:enabled="true">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name="com.intelligentcontroller.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter >
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

My English is not good and the whole paragraph was translated using a translator so please forgive me if there is anything strange in the code

Comment: There is a prerequisite that must be started once after the app is installed